# Adapt materialized view from oracle db to postgres

Tags: oracle, postgresql, materialized-views

I created materialized view in oracle and I used refresh force on demand option. Is there any possibility to adapt it to postgresql?

Answer (score 1):

`refresh force on demand` is actually the *only* option that Postgres currently supports (there is no `refresh next` or `refresh fast` in Postgres)

So there is nothing you need to do, just create the mview:

```
create materialized view mv_stuff
as
select *
from foobar;
```

Comment: Ok, but what if I added START WITH extra?

Comment: Changing the scope of the question after getting an answer is not the way this site works. You should state **all** relevant information in your quesiton. But `start with` is not supported either. Please read the manual, it's all explained there: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html